# Custom DateTime with Jackson using @JsonFormat like 30/06/2020 08:27 p. m

Tags: java, spring, datetime, jackson, datetime-format

I receive the date-time like `30/06/2020 08:27 p. m.` but the problem is that the Jackson API cannot deserialize this with `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a` pattern because of the dots.

I need help with the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `p. m.` with `pm` and `a. m.` with `am` before parsing.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String strDateTime = "30/06/2020 08:27 p. m.";

        // Replace p. m. with pm and a. m. with am
        strDateTime = strDateTime.replace("p. m.", "pm").replace("a. m.", "am");

        // Define formatter
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");

        // Parse the date-time string to LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, formatter);

        // Display ldt.toString()
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // Getting the date-time string back from LocalDateTime object
        String backToString = ldt.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(backToString);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-30T20:27
30/06/2020 08:27 pm
```